# Where do I find Bluetooth device Link Keys in 18.04?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm setting up a Bluetooth mouse for a Win10/Ubuntu dual-boot and need to get the link key in Ubuntu. Last time I did this, I found it in `/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC Address of device]/info`. After updating to 18.04, the info file looks much different and there's nothing that looks like a link key stored there.

Where do I get the link key now?

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC Address of device]` is the folder for the bluetooth device installed in your computer.

Inside this folder are many folders which correspond to each paired device. Each one if these folders have as name the corresponding id of the paired device. And inside each one of these folders exists the `info` file that you are looking for.

This link might help you if you want to pair a bluetooth device in a dual boot computer (Windows and Linux)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p